# Is it possible to have the Angular-Cli (angular v6) installed at the same time as nativescript-cli

Tags: nativescript, angular-cli-v6, nativescript-cli

I have been using angular cli (for angular v6) for months now running without issue. I have since discovered nativescript and decided it would be useful for me to learn, so I ran the quick setup script, which did work. But some time after, I noticed that the ng command no longer worked. I had a global install of the angular-cli, but when I listed the list of globally installed node modules:

```
npm list -g --depth 0

/Users/Zephilim/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib
├── nativescript@5.0.0
└── npm@6.4.
```

I realised that it (angular-cli/ng) appears to have been removed. Actually, here was my angular setup before nativescript destroyed it:

```
λ ~/dev/client/fix/material-pro-ng6/ ng -v
Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.7) is greater than your local
version (6.0.5). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.0.5
Node: 9.11.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.0.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.5
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.5
@angular/cli                      6.0.5
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.5
@schematics/angular               0.6.5
@schematics/update                0.6.5
rxjs                              6.2.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

There was no suggestion in the help documentation of nativescript that my angular cli would be removed.

Is this supposed to happen? How do I ensure that I can have access to both. Will reinstalling angular-cli break nativescript?

I am not sure what to do next. I was thinking about doing the full nativescript install, because there are still things that don't work with the quick setup.

Comment: It should not be an issue, at least I have both Angular and NativeScript CLI globally installed and running in my machine. Give a try, reinstall.

Comment: the angular cli and nativescript cli have nothing to do with each other, they wont break each other

Comment: yes, i use it simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, thats good to hear from multiple people. I must have something wrong with my setup. My annual full system rebuild is about due now so I'll start again from scratch on macOS mojave.

Comment: They are even meant to work together. Take a look at this blog post describing the recommended setup: https://blog.angular.io/apps-that-work-natively-on-the-web-and-mobile-9b26852495e7